# import key pair to pfx file without certificate chain in java

Tags: java, bouncycastle, pkcs#12

```
//Generate key pair
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

//Open a keystore
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(null, null);

//Setting a key entry
ks.setKeyEntry("test", pair.getPrivate(), password, **new Certificate[]{cert}**);
```

if i pass **null** instead of new Certificate[]{cert} or if i pass **new Certificate[]{}** i'm getting an error saying **"Private key must be accompanied by certificate chain"**.

So, without passing a certificate chain how can i import the key pair into pfx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While PKCS#12 specification allow to store private keys, Java `Keystore` does not support storing private keys without a certificate chain

See `KeyStore.setKeyEntry` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#setKeyEntry(java.lang.String,%20java.security.Key,%20char[],%20java.security.cert.Certificate[]))

> If the given key is of type java.security.PrivateKey, it must be accompanied by a certificate chain certifying the corresponding public key.